# TextEdit Chinese Plain Text Style Problems

Tags: macos, textedit

I'm working with Chinese text in TextEdit as a plain text .txt file.

This is what a normal line looks like: (and the style that my text document basically looks like)

[image: none]

> bai1 bai1   [pai⁵⁵ pai⁵⁵] (名) 瘸子、跛子。

this is a weird one:

[image: some]

> 儿端公——坐地使法  bai1 ber1 duan1 gong1——zo4 di4 si3 fa2  [pai⁵⁵ pər⁵⁵ tuan⁵⁵ koŋ⁵⁵ ——tso²¹³ ti²¹³ sɿ⁵³ fa²¹] (歇) 儿即瘸子、跛子之类的人士。端公即男巫。儿端公只好坐地使法。运用中指不亲自出面就在背后使用阴谋诡计。

I'm not sure why black text is suddenly looking kind of *grey* and *thin* - punctuation marks are likewise looking a little worse for the wear.

I think it may have something to do with the fact that I'm using a Unicode extension-B character (which may be using Hanazono font) giving everything behind it a weird look but I'm not sure. Also, this is plain text, I'm not really sure what could be interfering with it - but it's really starting to bug me. (it looks so nasty).

What can I do to fix my weird looking lines?

Comment: Please post the actual text as well as the image, so we can duplicate the problem without retrying.

Comment: Have you tried selecting the text and trying different fonts?  You may need to find one with all your characters to get uniform display,

Comment: @TomGewecke Added text to OP.

Answer (score 1):

I have so far only found one font which has all the characters -- Babelstone Han.   Try downloading that and switching the whole text to it.

Another possibility may be the MingLiu series of fonts that come with Word.

Of course plain text does not contain font info, so you are at the mercy of the the app and the OS regarding the fonts chosen, which will never be Babelstone Han unless this is installed and stipulated via rich text. In plain text I think you will always be stuck with two fonts which are unlikely to be identical in their display.

I notice, however, that your text above seems very even as displayed in my Safari.  I wonder what font it is using.

Comment: Another possible font is Hanazono split into HanaMinA and HanaMinB

Comment: I guess my question also is asking why one font affects an entire line in TextEdit and not just the specific characters themselves

Comment: @user3306356 I was not aware of the Hanazono series -- interesting. But as they are Japanese, they may have the Japanese hanzi variations instead of those for Chinese, I don't know.

Comment: @user3306356  Good question about TextEdit behavior when fonts are not specified.  I don't know why it does that or if there is any way to find out.  Does it seem to be ok if you do specify a font with all the characters?

Comment: If I specify HanaMinA for everything it looks all like my second "weird" picture - so yeah definitely a font issue.

Comment: @user3306356  How does it look with Babelstone Han??

Comment: kinda ugly, tbh.